# Stack WooCommerce Variable Pricing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a WooCommerce site with variable products. The variable products have two options: kit and pattern. The kit costs $17.99, and the pattern costs $6.99. I'd like to stack the prices, rather than displaying as a range. I'd like the prices to be stacked on the archive page as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Kit: $17.99
Pattern: $6.99

Comment: use product addons it will help you

Comment: These wouldn't be considered add-ons. Would I set up each product as a Simple Product, leave the price field empty, and then have a kit add-on and a pattern add-on? I haven't used this extension.